# Recursive subtarcting value from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with below details

```
 **SNo    DOP           PaymentFor  RequiredFee AmountPaid**
 600    8/6/2015    AnnualFee   400         200
 601    8/6/2015    AnnualFee   400         200
 612    8/7/2015    IDCardFee   50          5
 613    8/7/2015    IDCardFee   50          4
 614    8/7/2015    IDCardFee   50          3
 615    8/7/2015    IDCardFee   50          2
 616    8/7/2015    IDCardFee   50          6
```

I want to write a query to return the above details and one more column in mid with Balance as shown below. Initially Balance will be required fee then in next payment it will be required -paid amount for particular paymentFor.

```
 S.No   DOP         PaymentFor  RequiredFee Balance AmountPaid
 600    8/6/2015    AnnualFee   400         400     200
 601    8/6/2015    AnnualFee   400         200     200
 612    8/7/2015    IDCardFee   50          50      5
 613    8/7/2015    IDCardFee   50          45      4
 614    8/7/2015    IDCardFee   50          41      3
 615    8/7/2015    IDCardFee   50          38      2
 616    8/7/2015    IDCardFee   50          36      6
```

Comment: i tried using self join but was unable to get the result.

Comment: Take a look at [Lead and Lag][1] functions. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: This is a weird table schema. It assumes the primary key to be `S.No` and `PaymentFor`. So I take it there's only ever going to be one client? It holds no context for who's paying, so I assume so.

Comment: @Mark LEAD AND LAG are part of SQL server 2012 and above version. I am using SQL Server 2008. How It can be implemented in SQL server 2008

Comment: @insidesin: This is some part of my table schema. Yes S.No and PaymentFor will make Primary Key.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be storing the balance paid in different rows with different values. This means that your rows are only states and have no real reflection on what is **currently** paid.

i.e. If I were to go back and check the record for `S.No = 600`, I'd only know that the balance was 400 before payment, but who's to say it is 400 now?

It's not too wise to store the balance next to orders.

1. This method only means you have one client or one person *paying* and *buying*.
2. Primary key for the table relies on a `varchar PaymentFor` (and S.No).

If this is how you want the model ran, please ignore my post.

Comment: i think he is doing this because this sort of information is time related. So he may will check the record by the `DOP` and not by the `S.No`

Comment: It serves a good purpose now, but the larger it gets, the worse it'll get.. and quite fast. I would have gone down the path of calculating based on dates and costs, rather than a field in the table.

Comment: i have a similar table where each line represents a Month of a user roster and there i have also oldovertime, currentovertimeand a calcColumn which are the overtime at the end of the month and if i need to open a closed roster just to display the values i would also just use the date to get my rows

Answer (score 0):

> This query works ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86c94/1/0)):

```
; with fees(pOrder, SNo, PaymentFor, RequiredFee, AmountPaid) as (
    Select row_number() over(partition by PaymentFor Order By SNo), SNo, PaymentFor, RequiredFee, AmountPaid
    From Fee as f
), balance(Id, pOrder, SNo, PaymentFor, Balance, AmountPaid) as (
    Select 0, f.pOrder, SNo, PaymentFor, RequiredFee, AmountPaid From Fees as f Where pOrder = 1
    Union All
    Select id+1, f.pOrder, f.SNo, f.PaymentFor, b.Balance-b.AmountPaid, f.AmountPaid From Fees as f
    Inner Join balance as b On f.PaymentFor = b.PaymentFor and f.pOrder-1 = b.pOrder
)
select f.SNo, f.DOP, f.PaymentFor, f.RequiredFee, b.Balance, f.AmountPaid 
from balance as b
Inner Join fee as f On b.SNo = f.SNo
```

> What is does:

- First CTE (fees) makes sure there is not gap in SNo for each group of PaymentFor
- Second CTE (balance) does the recursive calculation
- Last Select adds missing parameters which are not needed nor used in the CTE

**Please note that it won't be really efficient if your table is or gets really large.** (lots of historical values) You may have to consider some changes on your model. This is not the best way to store such data.